# How to change desktop background to the next/prev background image with mouse right cick menu depending on wallch program?

Tags: 11.10, windows-7, menu, desktop-background, nautilus-script

I want a script or a tool to change the desktop background using mouse right click menu on the desktop to find in the menu Next and Previous buttons for the next and past background, but depending on Wallch(i know Wallch have quick-list menu), just like the right click menu of windows 7.

[image: Windows 7]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man wallch`:

> ```
>    --next
>        Proceeds to next image (random image selection if this is selected) if process is running.
>    --previous
>        It proceeds to the previous image (the selected options doesn't matter, previous pictures are logged).
>    --once
>        It  just  changes the desktop background choosing from the list. It works both if the wallch is open or not. 2 and more pictures have to be selected for this to work.
> ```

I have set up keyboard shortcuts to issue the commands `wallch --once` command and it works well.

Comment: OK it works i think i can now add Next background to the desktop context menu.

Comment: btw, I use `--once` because `it works both if the wallch is open or not`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a program called DesktopNova available in the Software Center.
It works in the same way as wallch and also has a tray icon (needs to be installed via software center "DesktopNova-Tray"). Then you can hover over the tray icon and use the mouse-wheel to change backgrounds.

Should work in Unity. Not sure if it works in Gnome 3

Comment: good one, but still need pop-up menu items like win-7

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is the possibility to set it to change the wallpaper by just hovering over the tray icon and use the scroll-wheel on your mouse if you dig thru the preferences...